# multiple urls pointing to one website iis

Tags: iis, web-hosting, windows-server-2012

I don't know whether it is possible or not please help me on this.

I have url1:  **mycompany.test.com**

url2:  **mycompany1.test.com**

My current customers using the URL1 for my product.I have got a requirement from one of our customers, that they want to use "mycompany1.test.com" instead of "mycompany.test.com".How to do that, and these both URLs should point to the same directory.These changes should not reflect for my remaining customers.

Comment: Have a look at [https://serverfault.com/questions/187931/iis-7-multiple-iis-sites-pointed-at-same-directory-how-is-this-accomplished](https://serverfault.com/questions/187931/iis-7-multiple-iis-sites-pointed-at-same-directory-how-is-this-accomplished)